# How to select many database rows using custom rule?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, select

I currently have a large table (millions of rows) with two columns: timestamp (ms) and value.

I want to be able to generate CSV files in PHP using the most recent value of an instrument at fixed time increments. To provide an example:

```
Table: data

timestamp  value
50         1
700        2
1500       3
2100       4
3100       5
3900       6
```

Assuming the fixed time increment is 1 second (1000 ms), the output should look like this:

```
timestamp  value
1000       2
2000       3
3000       4
4000       6
```

I am currently issuing many queries of the following form:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE timestamp<=2000 ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1
```

I then output each row to php://output and the user's browser downloads the file as it is created. However, this method of generating the data in the first place is turning out to be excessively slow given all the queries.

How can I speed up this process? I assume I should probably move most of the processing to MySQL to reduce the interprocess communication, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Is your `timestamp` indexed as a key? Also, how does "2100" in the first example become "3000" in the second?

Comment: No, there is a separate 'id' key which I did not mention. The reason is that at the position of 3000ms, the most recent recorded value was the one from 2100ms.

Comment: why is the value for `3000` `4` and not `5`? it always rounds up, not down to nearest value?

Comment: Correct. I am not looking for the nearest value, but rather the most recent value that would have been available at the timestamp of 3000

Comment: will there ever be two identical timestamps?

Comment: It is possible (although very unlikely) for there to be two identical timestamps, and in this case it does not matter which value is chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also round up each timestamp and then get the maximum TimeStamp of each rounded result.

```
SELECT
  a.RoundedTimeStamp, 
  t.Value
FROM(SELECT 
         CEIL(TimeStamp/1000)*1000 as RoundedTimeStamp, 
         MAX(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp
      FROM tablename
      GROUP BY CEIL(TimeStamp/1000)*1000
     ) a
JOIN tablename t
 ON t.TimeStamp = a.TimeStamp
```

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to this one because I am getting far better performance than with the others. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @drdanielfc . . . That is a good reason to change the answer.  Can you quantify the improvement?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In one sample set, your solution took over 2 minutes to complete while this one took about 4 seconds

Answer (score 3):

You want the values on the largest timestamp equal to or less than multiples of the increment 1000.  You can automate your process:

```
select 1000 * ceil(lt.timestamp / 1000) as timestamp, value
from data lt
where not exists (select 1
                  from data lt2
                  where lt2.timestamp > lt.timestamp and
                        lt2.timestamp <= 1000 * ceil(lt.timestamp / 1000)
                 );
```

An index on `data(timestamp)` should be helpful.

You can't quite do your formulation in MySQL, because MySQL does not support `limit` in these types of subqueries.

Comment: this one will be faster.

Comment: May I ask why an index on timestamp would be helpful?

Comment: The index can be used by the subquery.  So, (if MySQL cooperates) the subquery can be handled as an index scan over a small range of values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how performant this is going to be, because math and no indexes, but you can use a query like this:

```
select q1.nearest, q1.value 
  from
    (select t, 
            if(mod(t, 1000), (floor(t/1000) + 1) * 1000, t) nearest,
            if(mod(t, 1000), (floor(t/1000) + 1) * 1000, t) -t as diff,
            value 
      from data
    ) q1
  left join
    (select t,  
            if(mod(t, 1000), (floor(t/1000) + 1) * 1000, t) nearest,
            if(mod(t, 1000), (floor(t/1000) + 1) * 1000, t) -t as diff,
            value 
      from data
    ) q2
  on q1.nearest = q2.nearest 
    and q1.diff > q2.diff
  where q2.diff is null
```

with demo fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a199/13

Note this assumes no two timestamps will be the same.